# Stream grouping : children list to unique parent list

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I'm looking for a concise and efficient way to get a list of unique parents from a list of children using Java 8 streams.

For the example I have these two simple classes :

```
public class Child{
  private Parent parent;
  public Child(Parent parent){
    this.parent = parent;
  }
  public Parent getParent(){
    return this.parent;
  }
}

public class Parent{
  private List<Child> children;
  public Parent(){
    this.children = new ArrayList<Child>();
  }
  public void addChild(Child child){
    this.children.add(child);
  }
}
```

First I get a list of Child object from some method.
The children may belong to multiple parents with possible parents collisions.

```
List<Child> children = getChildren();
```

Then :

```
List<Parent> uniqueParents = children
  .stream()
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Child::getParent))
  .keySet()
  .stream()
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

So it works, but I'd like to avoid the double stream and collect.

Is this possible directly in one stream ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this:

```
List<Parent> uniqueParents = children
    .stream()
    .map(Child::getParent)
    .distinct()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try this

```
public Set<Parent> getUniqueParents() {
  return children.stream()
                 .map(child -> child.getParent())
                 .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
    Set<Parent> parents = new TreeSet<>();
    children.forEach(c -> parents.add(c.getParent()));
```

It is without streams but should solve the problem if you make sure to implement comparable. Could of course also use HashSet if you implement equals and hashcode.

Comment: Ok, but I need a list of unique parents, so I'll have to build a list from the set, which I'd prefer not to. I'd prefer to immediately get a list.

Comment: The set will contain unique elements only. You could create a List from this by doing list.addAll(parents). Be aware that the answer by Sánder also provides you with a Set.